# Normal bundle of "extra" curve in a fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a general $(4,1)$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3 \times \mathbb P^1$, which we think of via $\pi : X \to \mathbb P^1$, the projection onto the second factor, as a family of K3 surfaces.

For a genenal $t \in \mathbb P^1$, $X_t$ doesn't contain any $(-2)$ curves, but for special values of $t$ it does (for example, if the quartic contains a line).  Suppose that $C \subset X_t$ is a $(-2)$-curve on $X_t$.  What is $N_{C/X}$?

Of course it is an extension of $N_{C/X_t}$ by $N_{X_t/X}\vert_C$, i.e. of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)$ by $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}$.  But that could be either $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)^{\oplus 2}$ or $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}$, and I don't know how to distinguish.

Comment: If the induced map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to the moduli space of K3 surfaces is transversal to the Noether-Lefschetz locus at $t$, then the normal bundle is $\mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus 2}$.  You might want to see the following: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604222.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not an expert -- is this a condition that is checkable in practice?  I suppose this probably holds for general $X$ of my type as long as I know that the locus of quartic K3s is itself transversal to the Noether-Lefschetz locus.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the condition in practice, you can consider the following exact sequence
$$
0 \to N_{L/X} \to N_{L/\mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^1} \to N_{X/\mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^1} \vert_L \to 0.
$$
The second term is $\mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}$, the third term is $\mathcal{O}(4)$, and if $F(x_1,\dots,x_4,y_1,y_2)$ is the equation of $X$, and the line $L$ is given by $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ and $y_1 = 0$, the map is given by
$$
\mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O} 
\stackrel{(\partial F_/\partial x_1,\partial F_/\partial x_2,\partial F_/\partial y_1)(0,0,x_3,x_4,0,1)}\to \mathcal{O}(4).
$$
If it is an isomorphism on global sections, the kernel is $\mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$, otherwise it is $\mathcal{O}(-2) \oplus \mathcal{O}$, or even $\mathcal{O}(-3) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$.